# SP2010 company logo change using blank site

Tags: 2010

I am new to sharepoint 2010 and just created web application and selected BLANK SITE as template. Now trying to change the company logo but i am unable to do so. Even tried putting the my own logo in 14 hive's images and layouts/images also but its not picking the path and showing the following path.

http://10.21.21.188:90/_catalogs/masterpage/%20/_layouts/images/nheard_logo.gif

cant open the CSS using sharepoint designer. I guess if i choose team site as template then it would allow me to change the logo but not in blank site...plz advise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the icon for any site including Blank sites by opening Site Actions/Site Settings

[image]

and selecting "Title, description and icon" in "Look and Feel" section

[image]

You can then enter the URL to the logo.

[image]

The image will then be used as the logo for the site.

[image]

You can upload an image to a SharePoint Document Library if you want to host the image in SharePoint.

You should avoid manually editing or placing files in the 14 hive this will make maintenance much more difficult in the future.

To place files in the 14 hive you should create a SharePoint Solution file (.WSP).

You don't seem to need this complexity so I would advise uploading an image to a SharePoint Document Library

Comment: great..thank you for such a nice pictorial guidance :) two thumbs up...